# Centering elements in screen - ignore browser resizing

Tags: css, resize

I'm creating a "Site under construction" ilustration, but I'm having some dificulties in achieving the desired result. This is what I want:

[image]

Basically I want to center the 3 divs simultaneously - each one in it's own container (the **siteUnderConstruction_bg** must be centered in the body). As the browser resizes, the entire content should center intself on-the-fly.

HTML:

```
<div id="siteUnderConstruction_bg">
    <div id="siteUnderConstruction_text"></div>
    <div id="siteUnderConstruction_bars"></div>
</div>
```

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NRrRt/).

Help?

Pedro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NRrRt/1/

Add `background-position: top center` to the text and bars divs.

Comment: Totally forgot about background-position... thanx!